# How to pan a 2D openGL ES scene

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, ios5

Im trying to move an image around drawn with OGLES using glTranslatef in iOS. I know i can get the amount panned using a UIPanGestureRecognizer, but am unsure how to apply the deltas to the x and y variables. Any ideas how to accomplish this or know of a better way to pan around an image in openGL ES 1.1?

How im setting up my view:

```
    CGRect rect = view.bounds;
glViewport(0, 0,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); 
glOrthof( 0,rect.size.width,-rect.size.height, 0, -1, 1 ) ;  
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to do it. I normally change where the camera is located. Depending on the rotations you're using, everything can get out of whack if you do a glTranslatef at the beginning of rendering. How are you setting up your camera?

Comment: its a 2D view, and im not doing any rotation. glTranslatef(0,0,0) focuses on the center of the image

Comment: If you want to pan just in the X-plane, you can use glTranslate(xVal, 0, 0); Were you hoping to pan around outside of this plane? What are you using to set up your view matrix?

Comment: im trying to pan around by using my finger, so the one part im missing is how to update that xVal. Will edit my post with the code im using to setup my view.

Comment: Let me know if my answer below is what you're looking for. I was confused because I originally thought you wanted to do this in 3D and not in a projected 2D space.

Comment: For this my problem isnt specifying the value, but how to calculate the amount to be panned by dragging a finger across the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect rect = view.bounds;
glViewport(0, 0,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); 
glOrthof( xPan,rect.size.width + xPan,-rect.size.height + yPan, yPan, -1, 1 ) ;  
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```